# Build creation fails in Visual Studio for test written using selenium references

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

When i create build after creating a build definition for a test project developed using selenium references it throws me an error as follows.

"**The type or namespace name 'OpenQA' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

Even though i have used appropriate references in my project and it does not throw any error while running the test.

Error remains the same on adding reference as.

**Using OpenQA;**

What i am planning to do is to create a test a project using selenium references and execute it using Test Manager.

Please Help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Selenium libraries?

Comment: My best guess is `no` @Arran.  `:)`

Comment: problem is, with all of us, in these In dont understand problems, things seems to work just fine locally. BUT then you migrate to the build server, all sort of hell breaks loose. I've been working on Making selenium work with TFS - I'm four weeks into this problem. Still no cigar. Using MsTest v2 make it even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

While creating a build definition, under 'Process', in 'items to build' we need to set proper 'configurations'. Using 'Configurations' as 'release' and platform as 'x86' or according to your CPU will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arran stated.. The evidence suggests that you really **do not** have the appropriate assembly references.

Excerpt from the [WebDriver Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#c) -

> As of Selenium 2.2.0, the C# bindings are distributed as a set of signed dlls along with other dependency dlls. Prior to 2.2.0, all Selenium dll’s were unsigned. To include Selenium in your project, simply download the latest selenium-dotnet zip file from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list. If you are using Windows Vista or above, you should unblock the zip file before unzipping it: Right click on the zip file, click “Properties”, click “Unblock” and click “OK”.
>
> Unzip the contents of the zip file, and add a reference to each of the unzipped dlls to your project in Visual Studio (or your IDE of choice).

Comment: I have used following dlls

Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll

ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll

WebDriver.dll

WebDriver.Support.dll

and i am not able to figure out the issue because test runs fine when executed standalone but build creation is failing using build definition.

Comment: @VarunBajpai, make sure Copy Local is set to true in the properties window of each individual reference.

Comment: Using 

using WebDriver.OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using WebDriver.OpenQA.Selenium;

also provides no help..!!!
compilation fails....

Comment: @Arran, Copy Local is set to true for all the references.

Answer (score 0):

Just encounter the same issue. But this time, for me, the problem was because of an incompatibility between the **Target framework** of the application (old .NetFramework 4.5) and a more recent version of Selenium NuGet package (4.18.1).

A cheap **solution that worked for me**: upgrading the Target framework of the application to .NetFramework 4.8.

I guess it could've also work by using an older version of Selenium as well